# Regression like display for the data Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here is my dataset: [t.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/5a573831a0830172b508246cdfb7691f)
I am looking for a display like this:
[image]
The red dot for negative value, grey for 0, and blue for positive.
I tried to refer the example from the : [Logistic Regression](https://github.com/NSAryan12/nn-from-scratch/blob/master/nn-from-scratch.ipynb)

```
def plot_decision_boundary(pred_func):
    # Set min and max values and give it some padding
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
    h = 0.01
    # Generate a grid of points with distance h between them
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    # Predict the function value for the whole gid
    Z = pred_func(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    # Plot the contour and training examples
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
```

Got the above function for the plotting but didn't understood it.
I want to have the look as above image. How I can do it? Please let me know.

Comment: What would the scatter points represent for your dataset? ```df['real']``` vs ```df['prediction']```?

Comment: @jwalton3141 Scatter -- real  positive, negative, and neural values if any. Like the values with the + and - signs in the real dataset. The background it the prediction. The negative has
 red and positive has blue color and if neural than grey color would do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still struggling to understand. For the scatter values, ```df['real']``` are the x-values, but what are the y-values?

Comment: Sir we can tak ethe x-values as the total count of the `df['real']` where as `df['real']` are the y-values. As per my assumption. Am I correct or is there anything I am missing? Please let me know .

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Please see my post below and let me know if it's on the right lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's start by loading your data

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/home/b2003864/t.csv', header=0)
```

Next it's easy enough to get the scatter points you desire using `ax.scatter`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Plot positive values in red (C3)
ax.scatter(np.argwhere(df['real'] > 0), df.loc[df['real'] > 0, 'real'], color='C3', edgecolors='k')
# Plot negative values in blue (C0)
ax.scatter(np.argwhere(df['real'] < 0), df.loc[df['real'] < 0, 'real'], color='C0', edgecolors='k')
# Plot neutral value in grey (C7)
ax.scatter(np.argwhere(df['real'] == 0), df.loc[df['real'] == 0, 'real'], color='C7', edgecolors='k')
```

Finally, we can use `ax.fill_between` to plot the shaded areas, as you desired:

```py
ax.fill_between([-5, 35], -0.002, 0, color='C0', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)
ax.fill_between([-5, 35], 0, 0.002, color='C3', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)

ax.set_ylim([-0.00015, 0.00015])
ax.set_xlim([-5, 35])
```

All this together gave me:

[image]

Comment: Yes I am getting this is right I want the positive and negative nd neutral values scattered.

Comment: Okay, we're on our way. The neutral values are the zeros?

Comment: Yes, they are.. I guess I can fit it.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Yes sir it worked... It separated the values.... Now, please let me know how we can create a contour based background that will show the predictions

Comment: This really should be another question. See my edit (which I don't think is what you want) and please consider accepting this answer and starting a new thread about showing contour of predictions.

Comment: Sir , can you please use the columns from the csv, so that I can understand that. This only can get positive or negative I guess.

Comment: I have added the question sir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826721/background-contours-based-on-data-matplotlib-python Please let me know what I can do